# Custom URL encoding with HttpEncoder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to override the default encoding of HTML and URLs in a custom `HttpEncoder` class. The class is registered in the web.config file and appears to work just fine for the HTML encoding, but the overridden methods for encoding the URL is never called. Looking through the .NET source it appears it should be, but perhaps I am missing something.

My encoder looks like:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class CustomHttpEncoder : HttpEncoder
    {
        protected override void HtmlEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
        {
            base.HtmlEncode(value, output);
        }

        protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
        {
            base.HtmlAttributeEncode(value, output);
        }

        protected override string UrlPathEncode(string value)
        {
            return base.UrlPathEncode(value);
        }

        protected override byte[] UrlEncode(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count)
        {
            return base.UrlEncode(bytes, offset, count);
        }
    }
}
```

In a razor page I am using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", "controller", new { urlParam = "a spaced param" }, null)
```

The encoder is registered in the web.config as:

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="MyProject.CustomHttpEncoder" />
```

Setting a breakpoint in the `HtmlEncode()` or `HtmlAttributeEncode()` methods in the `CustomHttpEncoder` class works great. I can see all the various bits of the page run through the encoder including the title of my link.

However, the generated URL from the link (`/controller/action/a%20spaced%20param`) is never run through my encoder at either `UrlPathEncode()` or `UrlEncode()`. It obviously gets encoded somewhere, but where?

The docs and all my Google searching indicate this should work as pretty much everything gets run through the registered `HttpEncoder` vis the `HttpUtility` class.

I should note this is just an example I am using of trying to intercept the encoding for the URL and I am not trying to do something like replace spaces with the `"+"` in some variants of URL encoding. I want to be able to intercept any pattern in the encoding.

Comment: You need to show how your registering this in the web.config?

Comment: As there is only one way and it is obviously working for the HTML encoding I did not think that was necessary, but I will edit to include that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the type(CustomHttpEncoder) in `web.config`.

```
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime encoderType="CustomHttpEncoder, AssemblyName"/>
    </system.web>
```

Note that you’ll need to replace AssemblyName with the actual name of your assembly.If you put your encoder in a namespace, you’ll need to make sure to provide the fully qualified type name.